# how to share user libraries across multiple systems without exporting and importing

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie, Please bear if i am silly. I have created a java project in eclipse which uses includes multiple jars like Apache Commons DBCP, dbutils, commons pool and some mysql jdbc driver. Instead of adding these jar directly to the project, i want to create different user libraries one for each and add the respective jars and its source and its javadoc into it.

So i created the user libraries and added the respective things in it and added those user libraries into project. Everything is fine upto that. But I want to work with same project in my home machine and when i imported that into eclipse in my home machine, those user libraries are empty. I undestood eclipse stores those info in the workspace and in my new workspace i am not able to use that libraries.

So i tried creating a new folder "lib" in the project and added all those jar into that folder which will always go with the project and when i creating the user libraries, this time while adding the jars i selected the option add jar-> workspace->lib->... and added those jar into the user library assuming that the lib folder is within the project and so the user libraries stay accros the workspaace but i failed again. Its working out. So how can use the libraries in different workspaces without importing and exporting... Please help me...

I do know ${project_loc} will give the project location. So is there anything i can say ${project_loc}/lib/commons-dbcp.jar to the user libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are viewing `Package Explore`

Open the `Project Explorer` instead.

Comment: Either Package Explorer or Project Explorer, it does not matter. If my workspace changes then those jars inside the user library are gone.I want that to be as a user library across multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest to look at [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org), which does allow you to configure dependencies for your project and build it (almost) everywhere.

It also has some plugins for integrate with Eclipse, so you can share your project easily without copying libraries manually.

Comment: Hey Thanks. But i dont want to use any tools or plugins since i ll explaining some basic things about eclipse to students and i dont want to confuse them with these plugins.

Comment: Why don't you teach students proper way of being software engineers? They will never use those "user lib" in 99% cases, but knowledge of Maven/Ant/SBT/Gradle is a must nowadays. It's offtopic of course, but still.

Comment: OfCourse i understand. But what we software engineers really doing these days. For each and every thing we depends upon some sort of tools. They can learn Maven at some point when they really want Maven but some basic things if they miss at the initial stage then they wont look back again. Sorry about my thought. Since  Eclipse is such a powerful ide, we do have some way to achieve this...

Comment: Okay, I got your point. Perhaps you might want to try different IDE? I would strongly recommend Intellij IDEA, as far as I remember it allows you to configure project libraries as "bundles" and take ones with the project.

Comment: Thanks Again. But i am digging into eclipse to find the way.